# Too many if or nested loop in excel

Tags: excel, loops, if-statement, nested

I have a code that has way too many nested statements

Basically I have 1 cell to be compared with 100 cells and those 100 cells have their own value, and Excel only have max 64 if loops.
Any suggestions?

A=B =>> X=B1

A=C =>> X=C1

A=D =>> X=D1

A=E =>> X=E1

```
IF(L2=S2,T2,IF(L3=S3,T3,IF(L4=S4,T4,IF(L5=S5,T5,IF(L6=S6,T6,IF(L7=S7,T7,IF(L8=S8,T8,IF(L9=S9,T9,IF(L10=S10,T10,IF(L11=S11,T11))))))))))
```

Thanks!

Comment: If the values `B`, `C`, ... are in a column you may add another column like `IF($A = B; true; false)` then fill so it is `$A = C`, `$A = D` etc., then using `VLOOKUP` to get first `true` value.

Comment: Your example of using if contradicts your statement about "1 cell to be compared"

Comment: The 1 cell i use the drobbox list in excel, in my ex script L2 cell, compared with S2 cell if true, use value from cell T2

Answer (score 2):

I think table lookup is much simpler than a bunch of ifs:

```
=HLOOKUP(Value,{"Cond1","Cond2","Cond3";"Res1","Res2","Res3"},2,FALSE)
```

or

```
=VLOOKUP(Value,{"Cond1","Res1";"Cond2","Res2";"Cond3","Res3"},2,FALSE)
```

Even more simple if your conditions and results are continuous ranges

Answer (score 1):

There is a hard limit of 7 nested `if` in Excel.

[Here is a trick](http://sunburst.usd.edu/~bwjames/tut/excel/adv/26if.html) to increase this limitation.

Comment: I've tried, only 64 level of IF nested allowed, more than that error message will appear like : the specified formula can't be entered because it uses more than 64 level of nesting

Answer (score 0):

The following array formula may help:

```
={INDEX(A1:H1;1;MIN((IF(L3:R3=S3:Y3;COLUMN(B1:H1);""))))}
```

`L3:R3` Data array 1 being compared
`S3:Y3` Data array 2 being compared
`B1:H1` Corresponding values for data arrays

`INDEX` will find the value from interection of row 1 and the column corresponding to the first match found. The sizes of arrays should match, otherwise the formula will give `#N/A`.

The formula is inserted with Shift-Ctrl-Enter, curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.